# Configuring JUnit Directory Structure in Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit

I have a Java Spring application with unit tests in the directory

`src/test` Specifically `src/test/com/client/rest`

I'd like to add a child directory here, something like

`src/test/com/client/rest/controllers`

Which contains the unit tests for all controllers of the application. I created a file in this directory with a "@Test" end-point, but did not do anything to POM.xml. When I run `mvn clean package` I get the following error

`The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory [path]. Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory.`

I tried adding this new directory as a testResource element under build in POM.xml, but that did not work. Prior to adding this new file, the tests ran fine with `<testSourceDirectory>src/test</testSourceDirectory>` under the build element.

How do I properly integrate this new JUnit directory into Maven?

EDIT: I moved my new file to the standard parent directory where the other JUnit test files are (`src/test/com/client/rest`) and it seemed to register fine. What is the best practice for storing JUnit class files, and is it worthwhile to try to create new child directories for organizational purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error comes from just running the `mvn` command from somewhere other than your project root.

> How do I properly integrate this new JUnit directory into Maven?

Follow the Maven Standard Directory Layout - https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Your tests should be under `src/test/java/com/client/rest/controllers` . They should then be discoverable and just work without any additional Maven configuration.

> What is the best practice for storing JUnit class files, and is it worthwhile to try to create new child directories for organizational purposes?

It is worth organizing your tests. I think the piece you're missing is that you are writing tests in Java so you need to organize your tests with both directories and packages. So a test located under `src/test/java/com/client/rest/controllers` would have a package of `com.client.rest.controllers` .